# Is it possible to make a stopped process survive a shutdown?

Tags: mac, command-line, signal

I know that a program can receive a `STOP` signal and just sit there until it receives a `CONT` signal. Now knowing exactly how this works, I'm curious whether whether there's any way to have a `STOP`ped program survive a shutdown.

**Edit based on feedback**: The program is a python script which simply takes a text file input, does some processing, and spits out a different file. No reliance on any network connections or specific computer state.

Comment: As state, the problem is too vague to answer. For example, if all the program's TCP connections are gone, has it "survived"? If the program crashes because it doesn't expect the system uptime to ever decrease, has it "survived"?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - Thanks for the comment, good point... I hadn't considered those as possible issues. Clarified the question.